# Imagick::resizeImage and Imagick::scaleImage seem to compress/blur image, even when told not to

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagick, image-compression

I have come across a strange and nit-picky issue with the PHP Imagick library's `resizeImage` and `scaleImage` methods. (client is unhappy, understandably as they are a photographer)

Whenever an image is resized, it seems that the image becomes **very slightly** compressed, and dark areas become slightly pixelated due to this compression. This happens even if I tell it to render at full quality as I will explain below.

Firstly, here is an example, including a 4x zoomed version where it is easier to see the problem:
[image: Compression Issue]

At first I assumed this was some problem with the interpolation method, but when I dug deeper, I realized that the image infact still becomes compressed **even when resized to exactly the same size!?**.

The example shown above is a perfect example of that. It is a 100x100 image which has been resized to 100x100 using this code:

```
$image->resizeImage($this->width, 0, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);
```

This also appears to have the same results, even though I was told it would be better:

```
$image->scaleImage($this->width, 0, Imagick::FILTER_CATROM, 1);
```

The fourth argument is `blur` ([see PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)), which I understand is so that thumbnail images become aliased, however, even when I reduce this value to as small as 0.001, nothing happens.

Even when I add this code in to set the image quality to 100%, it still happens:

```
$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
```

Can anyone explain to me why these artifacts are appearing in dark areas of images, and how I can prevent this from happening? These images resize perfectly fine in Photoshop, so it seems a unique issue with Imagick and not the image itself being unsuitable.

As I said, I know this is nit-picking, however my client is in fact a photographer and pristine image quality is of high importance to them.

Comment: Did you try blur of 0 as well?

Comment: Yes, a blur of 0 for some reason returns the same results with scaleImage, however, with resizeImage, if the blur is set to 0, it returns a black image, so I assume this has to be set.

Comment: Maybe try using one of the slower filters? The comments on the docs page indicate they give better results, and you're using the fastest one.

Comment: I've cycled through all the filters and from one to the next, none of them appear to be any closer to the original. Do you think I right to find it strange that an image should lose quality on resizing, even when being re-sized to the **same** size, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well it being the same size in pixels doesn't mean it's the same size in bits, and therefore will probably lose information.

Comment: I see, I'm wondering why however that data is lost in the resizing process, even when the blur level is set to 0

Comment: Turns out compression was in fact being added in by default, and since I ignorantly had disabled JPEG compression whilst playing with the filters, I hadn't realised this was an issue, but it is in fact the resize filters in unison with the JPEG compression that caused the issue. I used the FILTER_SINC method and it actually looks better than the original now. Fantastic! Thanks Jessica. I would accept yours as an answer but it is in the comments! You can post it up?

Comment: i am still unable to remove blur from the resized image. $img->resizeImage($pWidth, $pHeight, Imagick::FILTER_SINC, 0, false); Tried blur value from -10 to 10. 
Want to use this with http://www.ajaxblender.com/jquery-ui-crop-zoom-script.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different filter, the slower ones supposedly give better results.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and still unable to remove the blur from the image. tried all combinations. but finally i used **Sharpens**.

```
$viewport->unsharpMaskImage(0, 0.5, 1, 0);
```

and this looks better.
This is an additional.